# How can I keep my iterable value in loop with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Everytime I click on the button the argument is always the last value of {i} (in this case is 0) and I need to have the ordinary value to pass to the Redux action.

When I print inside my DIV working.

```
class MYCLASS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        var level = []; 
        for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            level.push(
                <div>
                    <div>{i}</div>
                    <button className='up' onClick={()=>this.props.callUp({i})}>HEREEE!!</button>
                    <button className='down' onClick={()=>this.props.callDown({i})}>HEREEE!!</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return level
    }

}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    callUp: (i) => dispatch(callUp(i)),
    callDown: (i) => dispatch(callDown(i)),
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you iterate through the loop you can store the value of `i` to a variable. Each time you iterate through the loop, you create a new instance of that variable. Then you can pass that variable into the `onClick` handler. Its current value will be used and stored in the memory of your array.

If you dont do this it will only use the final value of `i`

See codesandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-waterfall-kw0kb

```
import React from "react";

class Test extends React.Component {
  renderButtons = () => {
    var level = [];
    for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      const currentLevel = i;
      level.push(
        <div>
          <div>{currentLevel}</div>
          <button className="up" onClick={() => this.props.callUp(currentLevel) }>
            HEREEE!!
          </button>
          <button className="down" onClick={() => this.props.callDown(currentLevel) }>
            HEREEE!!
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return level;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderButtons()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Test;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  callUp: (i) => dispatch(callUp(i)),
  callDown: (i) => dispatch(callDown(i)),
})
```